# How to Join on multiple MySQL columns using Rails ActiveRecord Query Interface

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord Query that joins the tables 'table_a' and 'table_b' on two JOIN conditions:

```
ModelA
  .joins("
    join table_b on table_b.id = table_a.table_b_id and 
           table_a.some_column = table_b.some_other_column
  ")
  .where(table_b: { some_conditions })
```

It is possible to minimize/replace the raw MySQL in JOIN clause using ActiveRecord methods?

---

I tried the following:

```
ModelA
  .joins(:association_b)
  .joins("join table_b on table_a.some_column = table_b.some_other_column")
  .where(table_b: { some_conditions })
```

But it resulted in an invalid MySQL query ('AND' keyword is missing between two join clauses)

```
SELECT `table_a`.*
FROM `table_a` join table_b on table_b.id = table_a.table_b_id join table_b on table_a.some_column = table_b.some_other_column
WHERE `table_b`.`program_id` ...
```

Comment: It seems ActiveRecord by itself doesn't support this, are you comfortable using Arel?

Comment: Have you considering defining a scope, with that condition defined in it, and then joining that scope?

Comment: @SebastianPalma Thanks for your time. But I was looking for more ActiveRecord way to deal with DB Queries.

Comment: @sandre89 Do you mean association?

Comment: @PrathapB You're right, i meant association. Define an association, specify the condition inside it's lambda, and then use Model.joins(:associaton_name)